# Kendo UI MVC - No Intellisense in Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a project within another project (they're two separate projects inside the solution, but the files for one are inside the other). I'm trying to use Kendo UI MVC wrappers, but I can't get Intellisense to work on the project that's inside the other. It finds the dll just fine because the project compiles and runs properly, but there's no Intellisense. I've tried everything I could possibly think of to fix the problem, including the instructions on [their support site](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting#visual-studio-server-intellisense-does-not-show-mvc-htmlhelper-extension-method), but nothing works. Only HtmlHelper isn't found, everything else works properly in controllers and elsewhere.

The specific issue is with my `@using` statement:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'Kendo' could not be found (are you missing
>   a / using directive or an assembly reference?)

My Web.config files are nearly identical between the working and broken projects, `Kendo.Mvc.UI` is referenced there as it should be, I've rebooted my computer, closed/opened the project, removed and re-added the reference, *everything*.

What can I do to fix Intellisense in these Razor views? I'm on MVC 5, all packages are fully up-to-date. Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Try to clean your solution and rebuild and see. If that does not work, Try to restart VS.

Comment: @Shyju As I mentioned in the second to last paragraph, I've cleaned, rebuilt, rebooted the computer, restarted VS, all of that kind of stuff.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov VS 2015 Update 1.

Comment: How did you add Kendo to your project?

Comment: @ataravati It's in my web.config (in the Views folder) and I have it at the top of the file with `@using`. It's referenced in the Program Files folder that it installs to, and Copy Local is True.

Comment: You don't need `@using`, if it's already referenced in your web.config file. You've also added a reference to Kendo.Mvc.dll to your project, right?

Comment: Do you have a Telerik ASP.NET MVC Application template when you try to create a new project in Visual Studio? If yes, have you ever tried that?

Comment: @ataravati I added the reference to Kendo.Mvc.dll, yes. I do have the template when creating a new project, but this was an established project that we're now adding the MVC wrappers to (it's currently using an outdated version of the open-source JS framework).

Comment: @Vaindil, so, when you use the template you don't have that problem?

Comment: @ataravati No, I do not have that problem when using the template. It's only on this one specific project within the solution. I bet it has something to do with the fact that the files for this project are within the files for the other working project, but I don't know what I could do to resolve that.

Comment: Did you follow this? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: You can also install Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio Extensions, and then use the Upgrade Wizard:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/upgrade-wizard

Comment: @ataravati Yes, I specifically stated in the OP that I followed the support site instructions. I'm running the upgrade wizard now.

Comment: @ataravati Upgrade wizard completed with no errors, still no Intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the actual problem was, but I moved the sub-project to not be underneath the other project and the problem is resolved.